# What happens to total resistance in a parallel branch when you slowly turn down the value of a variable resistor on one branch to zero?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Say i have a parallel circuit with a resistor on each branch. If I take one of the resistors and decrease the resistance, the total resistance in the should decrease right? But if it goes all the way to zero, would it turn into effectively a series circuit and cause the resistance to jump back up?

Image of the Circuit
https://ibb.co/zhWG8Gx

X is a variable resistor

Comment: Welcome to Phys.SE! Could you provide a little more detail on the problem? In the way the question is currently phrased, it is hard to tell how exactly the circuit is assembled. If you could provide a picture (even if it is hand-drawn or drawn on MS Paint) it would be of great help =)

Answer (score 4):

*But if it goes all the way to zero, would it turn into effectively a **series** circuit and cause the [total] resistance to **jump back up**?*

should read

. . . . if it goes all the way to zero, it [would] turn into effectively a **short** circuit and cause the [total] resistance to **become zero**.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that reducing a resistance to zero is equivalent to taking it away. The equivalent to removing one branch of a parallel circuit is to introduce an infinite resistance into it, which removes the branch as a possible path for current.